# How can I `kubectl explain` the entire structure of a custom resource?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a CR in the cluster. I know that there is a filed `specialField` somewhere in this CRD. I do not know where it is. Right now I am randomly exploring the CRD using `kubectl explain path.to.some.filed` to try to fiend the filed. Is there some way to explain the entire nested structure using `kubectl explain`?

What I am looking for is something like this

```
kubectl explain-magic my-crd

my-crd
 a
  b
   c
 other
  field 
 more
  fields
 very 
  nested
   field
```

or as an alternative

```
my-crd
a
a.b
a.b.c
other
other.field
more
more.fields
very
very.nested
very.nested.field
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Add the --recursive flag to display all of the fields at once without descriptions. Information about each field is
> retrieved from the server in OpenAPI format.

from `kubectl help explain`.

Just do: `kubectl explain --recursive my-crd`

Comment: Thanks. I love you for that. That is amazing!